# MarkLogic: list all JSON in directory and transform in another JSON format with metadata

Tags: json, marklogic

There are a number of JSON files of same format lie in directory `/report-types`. They look like this `FITP.json`:

```
{
    "reportTypeId": "FITP",
    "reportName": {
        "translations": {
            "*": "Fixed Income Two Pager"
        }
    },
    "reportParameters": [],
    "outputFormats": [
        {
            "format": "word",
            "styleSheet": "word_FITP.docx"
        }
    ],
    "body": {
        // comments not allowed in JSON, but here comes so much irrelevant stuff
    }
}
```

I want to create a MarkLogic REST query (preferably `POST`), which

1. goes through all JSON files in directory `/report-types`
2. transforms them in the example above to following JSON:

```
{
    "reportTypeId": "FITP",
    "reportName": "Fixed Income Two Pager",
    "outputFormats: [ "word" ],
    "createdAt": "", // again invalid comment, but insert time stamp of creation here (file metadata?)
    "modifiedAt": "", // same here, for modification date
}
```

3. returns these result JSONs as array in the response

Which query endpoint should I use for this task,

- `.../LATEST/qbe?directory=/report-types`
- or `.../LATEST/search?directory=/report-types`
- or something else?

How does the transform query (embodied in the `POST` request) look like, that provides me with the desired result?